# Email results of a query using SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I have a table called `Customer` in SQL Server Express. I have run the script shown here to find customers that have not bought anything within a given month:

```
Select *
From Customer
Where Credit < 0 Between '2020-09-01' And '2020-09-30'
```

I would like to email these results, but I just don't know how to go about it since I am using SQL Server Express. Any ideas that may be able to help with this?

Comment: What format do you want to send?  A file, csv data, a picture, or some other format?

Comment: You can use Database Mail in SQL Express: https://www.sqlshack.com/database-mail-configuration-in-sql-server-express-edition/

Comment: Hi  friend. You can create some program to simulate SQL Server Database Mail. The procedure will be query the table and then sent the emails using pieces of code (external to sql server).
In addition I think the query have a little mistake; `Where Credit <= 0 Between '2020-09-01' And '2020-09-30'`
[SmtpClient Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.5.2)
[Send Mail Using Gmail account](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-smtp-mail.htm)
[Send Email in C#](www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sending-email-using-c-sharp/)

Comment: Loop through recordset and build string of data for inclusion in email body. Can probably use HTML tag code to build a table. What are you using for database interface?

Comment: I would like to send it as a pdf if possible